# como eliminar datos repetidos en sql

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo que hacer esto
Listar el primer apellido de los empleados eliminando los apellidos que estén repetidos

como lo puedo hacer

esta es la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

exactamente son las que están repetidas a qui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los apellidos que este repetidos tengo que eliminarlos

Comment: Hola! Veo que ya hiciste el recorrido. Recuerda que las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

puedes utilizar el método **DISTINCT** o su homólogo **DISTINCTROW**.

***Ejemplo***:

- SELECT DISTINCT(apellido1) FROM tb_nombre
- SELECT DISTINCTROW(apellido1) FROM tb_nombre

Nota: no te olvides de chequear la documentación para mayor información. Cómo no especificas el DBMS, entonces puedes consultar tambíen:

- https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/predicados-all-distinct-distinctrow-o-top-24f2a47d-a803-4c7c-8e81-756fe298ce57
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-microsoft-access-sql
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: En las etiquetas, el OP especificó MySQL.

Comment: Las etiquetas de la pregunta si lo especifican, usa MySQL

Comment: Gracias por la observación. Es mi primer día e incluso mi primera respuesta, debo adaptarme a la plataforma.